# „Saisonende“ or „Saisonabschluss“?

Tags: translation, difference, meaning-in-context

Mein Team hat eine Einladung zum „Saisonabschluss“ oder „Saisonende“ erhalten.

What is better ?

Comment: It's best not to mix languages in questions, either all German or English with German in *italics*, **bold** or "quotes" (or some combination) when necessary. Just use the language you're most comfortable with. Also context is helpful; is this an end of summer celebration, an end of the concert season, or something else? I assume also that you meant "Mein Team hat ... ."

Comment: @RDBury yes, It's about the end of the sports season. The team received an invitation to the closing of the sports season.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Saisonende" would be mostly understood as a point in time, as the end of the season. You could use it, for example, to denote an appointment:

> Die Hotelzimmer sollen zwei Wochen nach Saisonende renoviert werden.

"Saisonabschluss" would be mostly understood more as a process, a task or an activity:

> Während des Saisonabschlusses müssen alle Kühlschränke leergeräumt und gereinigt werden.

So regarding your invitation, if you want to talk about the time of the event, "Saisonende" would probably fit better:

> Am Saisonende möchten wir alle Mitarbeiter zu einer Feier einladen.

If you want to talk about an event being part of the end of season rituals, for example, "Saisonabschluss" would probably fit better:

> Im Rahmen des Saisonabschlusses möchten wir alle Mitarbeiter zu einer Feier einladen.

But the difference isn't that big, so you will probably also see the words used the other way around as well.